# Unable to set multiple environment vars in Laravel Homestead config

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, vagrant, homestead

My yaml file looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/VagrantSites/project-base
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/project-base
    - map: ~/VagrantSites/craft-base
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base

sites:
    - map: local.project-base
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/project-base/public_html
    - map: craft.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base/public_html

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
    - key: APP_DEV_MODE
      value: true
    - key: APP_DB_SERVER
      value: localhost
    - key: APP_DB_DATABASE
      value: craft_base
    - key: APP_DB_USER
      value: homestead
    - key: APP_DB_PASSWORD
      value: secret
```

Presumably because I have the syntax wrong as i get this error:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

I tried removing the dashes on all but the first variable but then none get set at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error comes from the use of the word true.
In yaml boolean should be with their string version, "true" and "false".

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you would be better putting the environment variables on the project, since you might have more projects in the future with different databases for example.

For each project you would set your variables.

source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration

Comment: Thanks, we're actually using the Homestead environment for non-Laravel projects though, hence the reason for using the environment vars in the Homestead.yaml file. The variables would only ever be for local dev, so no security risk. It just seems there's a bug in the code that prevents the addition of more than one variable.